# Power Latching Relay off/on in response to 12V ignition and 1 second ground pulse

Tags: ground, timer, 555, pulse

I have the following sample schematic of a 12 volt automotive circuit to trigger about 60 seconds of power output to a latching relay on output pin 3 of the 555 Timer chip.

The schematic below is a just a sample and not the final circuit.  The 12 volt automotive battery is driving the circuit.  It requires 2 different types of input to the 555 Timer.

Inputs:

1) 1 second ground pulse coming from various Viper alarm outputs.  It is a floating Viper model-5906V (-) 200mA 1 second OUTPUT. (This input should turn the relay on for 60 seconds, once it sees ground.)

2) Turning the 12 volt ignition on should turn on the relay (set) and leave on as long as the ignition is on.

3) Turning the 12 volt ignition off should trigger the 555 Timer.  After 60 seconds the relay should turn off (reset).

4) Ideally if the ignition turns off and it has been 50 seconds (relay is still ON) and then the Viper alarm sends a 1 second ground pulse on the input, it should wait 60 seconds from the last input received.  I am not sure this is possible however without adding a 2nd 555 Timer to the mix.

[image: 555 Timer to Latching Relay]

The 555 Timer needs to be configured to turn on (set) the 12V Hella Latch Relay (Hella 933364027), specs are here: http://hellahd.com/index.php/default/electrics/relays/micro-iso-relays/electrics-product-12/ , when either of the above inputs are triggered.  The relay should turn off (reset) after the 60 second Timer output expires, this should expire 60 seconds after the last ground pulse from the alarm trigger, or 60 seconds after the ignition is turned off, whichever is later.

The circuit is used to supply power thru the latching relay to power assessories after the ignition is off for 60 seconds, with a provision to allow for remote controlled activation via the alarm's 1 second ground pulse.

Need assitance in getting the outputs to fire the latching relay contacts briefly with the above timing.  Currently the output signal to the Set (pin 1) contact is working but when I try to use that to power a transistor as in the example to the Reset (pin 2) it does not turn the transistor on.

How does this circuit need to be modified to set and reset the latching relay?

Comment: What is the relay coil resistance?  What voltage rating (12V presumably.) Several simple circuits are possible.  How fast does the 12V fall. Do you want the pulse AFTER the 12V is fully gone or when it starts to fall. If AFTER the 12V is gone the relay needs powering.

Comment: I will be driving a 12V latching coil (Hella 933364027), specs are here:  http://hellahd.com/index.php/default/electrics/relays/micro-iso-relays/electrics-product-12/    The coil resistance is 2 x 75 Ohm ± 10%.  The 12V is the ignition wire in a vehicle so it should fall off fairly quickly.  The igition wire will also power the coil so as soon as the ignition wire drops to 0V, it should turn on the 555 Timer.  I shouldn't need to compensate for the ms between those changes because i will be using a latching relay.  The output i did not show but it is taken care of already.

Comment: Definition of task now uncertain. Is the latching realy to emain on due to final pulse. Or is the pulse a delatching one. |Failure to properly descibe task wastes you time and ours. | Max data helps good answers. | Relay has a MAX pull in time of 10 mS. So your 1s spec is excessively hard.|| operating voltage (or a <6V not operating one). So you need > I = V/R = 7/75 = 40 mA. More is better. 80mA say  x 12V x 10 mS = ~ 0.01 Joule = nicely small. Dumping a say 22o uF onto the coild ould probably do. 2 x small cheap transistors, cap, 2 r's. diode. Later ...

Comment: Appoligizes for the output, I was trying to keep it simple.  The output of the 555 Timer is driving a NPN transistor to power the relay off/on, its a standard automotive relay and that is working properly.  Question is:  I need to have the 12V to 0V change trigger a small momentary ground to the 555 Timer input to start its countdown.

Comment: Thanks. Simplifying doesn't always do so :-). | I'm confused though -  The relay has a set/reset dual coil arrangement. How does the 555  do the two coil separate pulse arrangement? | Is the 15V present even when the 12V ignition voltage is removed?  . | A "simple" description of the whole cycle to make sure I have it clear would help. [Things that ARE in fact quite simple once properly appreciated can sometimes be remarkably hard to convey].

Comment: Testing with a standard relay & 12V to 0V timing has not been an issue cause I was assuming the relay would already be latched. I plan to begin using the 12V latching coil once I get the input ironed out. I do see your point. I have it all in my head, but its a bit confusing when I think about it. So I dont have a good answer for you yet on the latch trigger. I was planning to have the 555 send a GND signal to the relay set pin when its a high output on pin3, and then send a GND signal to the relay reset pin when its a low output on pin3.  I just have not drawn up that part of the circuit yet.

Comment: As I said: "| A "simple" description of the whole cycle to make sure I have it clear would help." | So far we have a link to a two coil latching realy that needs a 10 ms oulse, which you are not yet using. And a 555 permanent drive cct that exceeds the new relay's 1s MAXIMUM allowed coil operate time. And a turn off cct whose criteria we still don't know from a 15V supply we asked about the independence of but didn't get an answer. And... || PLEASE provide a simple description of what you actually want to do. NOT how you think you MAY achiever it but the actual aim.

Comment: Voltages and level changes etc and reasons and relative timings and .... . If you NEED a 1 second off pulse say so BUT if that's because you think the relay needs a 1 second pulse (it doesn't) then it's not part of what you wish to do.  | The problem is probably an easy one to solve, once we know what it actually is.

Comment: @Raptor: I see your edit but you haven't actually asked a question. What is it that you want to know?

Comment: @Russell McMahon I have updated the initial post with the entire goal of the circuit.  I was hoping to keep it simple so hopefully my end goal is clear now.  Thank you for you help.

Comment: @Raptor Q1 Do you need to use the set/reset relay? - It can be done BUT that means you need a latch pulse (<= (ie less than or equal to) 1 second) and a delatch pulse (also <= 1 second). Q2: Is thie following the COMPLETE Spec: When ignition is turned off relay turns on for one minute OR when alarm sends a 1 second ground pulse relay turns on for 1 minute. If so say Yes. If not, please provide complete spec with that degree of clarity and simplicity. Not HOW etc - just what you want to achieve.  ...

Comment: Q3 You say "... 1 second ground pulse..."  but your diagram shows R3 pullup with SW0 to ground. Is this IDENTICAL to what you mean by "1 second ground pulse? Q4 If A3 answer is "YES!" - how do you know? Is R3 in the alarm. Is the alarm contact floating? Or ? || All the above questions and prior interaction may well seem to you like lunacy :-) - BUT it is really hard to get an actual spec when it is simplified, added to, ... . I THINK the simple one sentence statement in Q2 is all and only what you want, but ... ? | Q5: Have you answered question 1 2 3 & 4 ? :-)

Comment: Q1 - Yes want to use latching relay to save power.  Relay will also be set on while the ignition is on.
Q2 - Ignition on should turn the relay on, turning the ignition off means the relay stays on for another 60 seconds.
Q3 - the AUX inputs are 1 second ground pulses.  The 100K pullup to GND allows for about a 1 second ground signal when the ignition is turned off.
Q4 - the alarm output is floating.

Comment: @Raptor Closer ... | Did you realise that the spec changed again? -> "Relay will also be set on while the ignition is on." appears to be new (unless I missed it before)(it happens.) || SO as I asked above: Q6 (new number)  If not, please provide complete spec with that degree of clarity and simplicity. Not HOW etc - just what you want to achieve. ||

Comment: [[eg ???: This is my example - YOU MUST provide the full spec. - Relay I wish to use is a latching relay - see datasheet link above - with a set coil and a reset coil. Datasheet shows that MAXIMUM allowed set or reset pulse time is 1 second and maximum REQUIRED pulse is 10 mS at 12V. | Required: Set relay when any of (i) ignition is on, OR (ii) for 60s after a FLOATING contact pulse of xxx ms (show datasheet) from viper alarm OR {iii) for 60s after ignition is turned off.  ||| Note - prior claims re setting relay when ignition is turned off are wrong as it is already set by on ignition.

Comment: SUMMARY: Provide a simple as possible, COMPLETE word spec of all that you want to do, & NONE of HOW unless it is essential. | eg latching relay is in spec as you insist you need it (even though current drain compared to car with ignition on is utterly trivial).  | Floating alarm trigger contact is in spec. | 1 second delay with RC is NOT in spec as it's part of "how" (and is wrong).  Pushbutton is not in spec as (apparently) there is no pushbutton (it's the alarm FLOATING) contact. ....

Comment: @Russell McMahon yes the requirements changed. I wanted to give u the whole picture, so the other circuit I had that turned on the relay when the ignition turned on I thought I would add for an all in 1 circuit so u could see the whole picture. I have edited the original post. I also added a new requirement which may change the input design. After some debugging their is a chance if the timing is just right, say at 59 seconds an additional ground is triggered, which could cause the relay to flip off and then on and would cause things like windows rolling up to halt. Looking 4ward 2 a response!

Comment: I suggest you reread above starting at " ...?: This is my example - YOU MUST provide the full spec. ..." - You keep adding and changing things, and also changing your diagram. It looks like you are going to get there by yourself at this rate (if that's your own work) but asking us to try to match an ever changing and incomplete spec is  not realistic. Doing it yourself your way is fine. I'd have started with a CD4016 / 74C14 IC - similar ability to 555 but 6 per package and very flexible. BUT ...

Comment: arguably the best and simplest solution is a <$5 Arduino and a few glue components. You can then change functionality to suit as much as you want. 12V level inputs take a few resistors (and maybe a capacitor and/or zener. maybe). 12V outputs are a transistor and resistor. After that an extremely simple program can be adapted as required.

Comment: @Russell McMahon not sure I follow. This is now the full spec. Are you referring to not using the 555 and I should remove that from the spec? What would you recommend given this:

Comment: Inputs:

1) 1 second ground pulse coming from various Viper alarm outputs. It is a floating Viper model-5906V (-) 200mA 1 second OUTPUT. (This input should turn the relay on for 60 seconds, once it sees ground.)

2) Turning the 12 volt ignition on should turn on the relay (set) and leave on as long as the ignition is on.

3) Turning the 12 volt ignition off should trigger the 555 Timer. After 60 seconds the relay should turn off (reset).

Comment: 4) If the ignition turns off and it has been 50 seconds (relay is still ON) and then the Viper alarm sends a 1 second ground pulse on the input, it should wait 60 seconds from the last input received.
Output needs to trigger a 12V Hella Latch Relay (Hella 933364027)

Comment: @Raptor This is unclear: "Ideally if the ignition turns off and it has been 50 seconds (relay is still ON) and then the Viper alarm sends a 1 second ground pulse on the input, **it should wait 60 seconds from the last input received."** -> What is "it" what waits for what. Is "last input" from viper  alone or also from ignition on or off or ... . || Again WHY the latching relay eg [THIS](http://hellahd.com/index.php/default/electrics/relays/mini-iso-heavy-duty-relays/electrics-product-1/) Hella relay is 60A rated and draws about 150 mA when on. That's significant if it's the only load - but...

Comment: in a motor vehicle when you turn the ignition on you have some amps drawn -  before lights, radio, other accessories. 150 mA will be maybe 5%-10% and maybe under 5%.  I can provide a circuit that does what you ask. But, is it really needed. || A: YES, I really want the latching relay. / NO it's not really needed :-).

Comment: @Russell McMahon When an input is triggered, the relay should turn on (if not already on) and remain on for 60 seconds.  But if the ignition is on it will need to remain on until the ignition is turned off.  So the requirement is to keep the relay powered on for 60 seconds after the last input.  For example if you turn off the ignition the 60 second count down timer starts.  If at 30 seconds it gets a ground pulse then the count down timer should reset to 60 seconds.

Comment: You are correct in that the "latching" relay is NOT needed.  I could get this circuit working much easier without it.  But since I was already building this circuit I wanted the challenge of using a latching relay.  They have always intrigued me so I wanted to use one for the project because I have some other projects where I need to leave a relay latched when the power is off and dont want a high current drain, so figured this was a great example to work out the details.

Comment: Also the way the new push to start vehicles are wired, at least in this case, there does not seem to be an accessory power option so the ignition may be left on at times to power the radio.  In that  case, I did not want to have the additional current drain.  Plus the  vehicle can power off for long times with the auto-off feature and I was trying to avoid that curent drain as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a circuit that may meet your requirement.
Inverters are a package of hex Schmitt trigger inverters.
MUST be Schmitt trigger.
There are two spare inverters which can be used in various ways if desired.

You could convert this to a '555 based circuit with more components and less "properness". eg here the 1 second delays are driving a Schmitt triggered CMOS input.

D1 accepts 12V positive on ignition
D2 accepts a 12V positive going alarm pulse. As the contact is floating this should not be a problem. If desired you can invert either input sense with a spare inverter.

When either input is high, Q1 inverts this to low and D3 keeps C2 discharged.
An alarm pulse occurring during a R2C2 timeout resets the timeout.

When neither input is high R2 charges C2. A 1 minute delay could use eg about 10 uF / 4M7 . Values will need to be "select on test"ed.

R1C1 and R3C3 plus following inverters provide 1 second delays.
A negative going edge pulls the cap low and the resistor then charges it high.
When the alarm pulse activates C1R1 the output pulse lasts the lesser of the alarm pulse or C1Ra timeout. As the set/reset relay only needs a 10 ms pulse 'this is not a problem".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjytZI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**__________________________________________**

**Added:**

Extra inputs eg floating/ground on/off

If you follow my circuit and see how it works it should be possible to add to it with the spare inverters or modify it.

"Floating" inputs are best pulled to non active state with a pull up/down. This can be behind an input diode (see eg existing Ignition-D1-R6 where D6 pulls the input to ground if Ignition is open) to ensure input idle state is defined.

If voltages spike too high, clamp them to relevant rail (12V or ground) with a diode.
eg in existing circuit the input to IC3 spikes to 2 x supply when IC4 out goes high.
A diode across R3 (Cathode/bar to V+) stops this.

Comment: Thank you @Russell McMahon I may need to order some more hex Schmitt trigger inverters, but will try it out!

Comment: the circuit works great!  Now that it is built I have found 1 additional input needed.  I need to have a constant ground act the same as an incoming pulse. I can use an inverter to make it high as well, the difference is it needs to act as a pulse to the input for about 1 second and then not trigger again unless ground is removed and then triggered again.  I have it working with a RC circuit but must be missing the correct capacitor discharge because after ground is removed I cannot get it to trigger again.  Any ideas?  Thanks for the help.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @Raptor My circuit should turn the relay on on a rising edge and off on a falling edge.  Your added requirement is ambiguous - can you please spell it out in step by step detail. A constant ground inverted with a spare inverter and then fed in via D2 should act the same as ignition on D1. Either a detailed word picture or a sequence diagram is needed.

Comment: - this input is floating input that supplies a constant ground when activated.  It can remain at ground for 1 second or 24 hours.  The requirement is when ground is received it should activate the relay for 60 seconds and then turn it off.  Simlar to the 1 second input pulse, but because this input is constant the 60 second timer should start as soon as the ground signal is received.  The Ignition signal does not start the countdown 60 second timer until the ignition turns off.

Comment: While this input needs to start the 60 second off timer as soon as the relay is activated and, then turn off the relay in 60 seconds if no other input has activated it.  Ignition would continue to keep the relay on if the ignition was on after this signal was received.  Ultimated just need to change this constant ground into a 1 second pulse and it could be fed into IC1.

Comment: I played around with an RC timer but it was doubling the voltage during the capacitor discharge spike, which would end up frying the inverter.

Comment: @Raptor we are back to an almost defined spec that may be quite different than it appears. || If you follow my circuit and see how it works it should be possible to add to it wity the spare inverters of=r modify it. "Floating" inputs are best pulled to non active state with a pull up/down. This can be beyind an input diode (see eg Ignitioj-D1-R6) to ensure input idle state is defined.  ...

Comment: ... If voltages spike too high clamp them to relevant rail (12V or ground with a diode. eg in existing circuit the input to IC3 spikes to 2 x supply when IC4 out goes high. A diode across R3 (Cathode/bar to V+) stops this.

Comment: thank you the diode across R3 dropped the voltage spike from 8-9V down to about 5.5V, so hopefully that will be safe enough with the Inverter.  No issues during testing.  I appreciate all the help.  Will post design once I draw it up.

Comment: @Raptor I assume you means 5.6V spike relative to ground with a 5V supply. Using a Schottky diode will reduce it further so that the IC body diodes do not conduct.

Comment: "must be schmitt triggered" - do you think I could leave those schmitt triggers out if I used a potentiometer instead of a resistor in the RC delay group and tweak it to my desired time delay for a particular transistor ?

Comment: @kellogs The circuit MAY work OK without a Schott troggered IC but it is not worth doing so unless you are a month or more away from obtaining the ICs The 74C14 and CD40106should still be available and there are other equivalents.

Comment: @kellogs  The CD40106 is available from Mouser in various packages [here](https://www.mouser.com/_/?Keyword=cd40106&FS=True)